# directory reading in linux using php from windows shared folder on network

Tags: php, linux, windows

I need to read a directory from windows system share folder to PHP script in linux environment But the script displaying error "failed to open dir: No such file or directory"

How can i read the windows shared directory in linux using php?

Comment: Uhm, how are you reading it? What code are you using? What's the path? You should really provide more info

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do specific to PHP IMO if you're okay with mounting the Windows share on the Linux box using the following mount command:

`mount -t cifs -o username=WINDOWS_USER_NAME \\\\hostname\\sharename /mnt/myshare`

Then you should be able to read the files in the share from `/mnt/myshare` just like any other file within your PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for response. which username i have to add, Also please let me know mount is auto or everytime have to run?? is there any other way to read directly from network rather than  mount.

Comment: The username is the Windows username for the share. I'm not sure if PHP has any native support for `SMB` or `CIFS`.

Comment: fine, is there any other way to read files from windows system network shared folder to linux PHP?